# Can I clone my WIFI modem

Tags: wireless-networking, modem

I use an Wifi Modem which my Internet Service Provider gave which is a UTSTARCOM WA3002G4,
my problem is it has heat isssues on long run, is there a way to clone my WIFI modem onto another WIFI modem of like D-link, NetGear or Linksy so that I will have the same settings.

Comment: Are you looking for a wireless modem/router combo or a wireless router?

Comment: Combo is what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard format for moving all your home gateway settings from one device to another.  A few vendors use a standard format within their own products (e.g. if you have more than one Apple's AirPort product, you can export a ".baseconfig" file on one, and import it onto another) but those are not interchangeable between vendors.

If you buy a new device from your ISP, your ISP *might* be able to use a protocol called TR-069 to read/save the settings from your old device and write them to your new ISP-provided device, but that probably wouldn't be something they could do if your new device was just something you bought yourself from some other source.

Comment: similarly, you might be able to export/import settings on third-party firmwares like DD-WRT/OpenWRT, at least with some custom scripting, *if* you were using the same firmware version on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

If its a Modem (Assuming ADSL), check the configuration pages for the authentication details. Write that down and when you get a new router/modem, key those in during the config.

Your ISP should have given you the authentication stuff for your modem, if they didn't, try giving them a call.